# Multiple Bootstrap React components in one Bootstrap Row

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a "main Bootstrap row" that can house different React components in separate columns within that row, but since they are completely different React components, they want to render underneath each other. Im not sure if its a CSS, Bootstrap or React mistake I'm making.

Right now, I just need to render one component of `col-1` and a different component of `col-11` on the same Row, a simplified version of my code is as follows:

ReactApp.js:

```
Import React from "react";
Import {Container, Col, Row} from "react-bootstrap";
Import Comp1 from "./components/Comp1";
Import Comp2 from "./components/Comp2";

function App() {
 return (
  <Row>
   <Comp1 />
   <Comp2 />
  </Row>
 );
}
export default App;
```

Componenet1.js:

```
Import React from "react";
Import {Container, Col, Row} from "react-bootstrap";

const Comp1 = () => {
 return (
  <Col md={1}>
   <content>
  </Col>
 );
}
export default Comp1;
```

Componenet2.js:

```
Import React from "react";
Import {Container, Col, Row} from "react-bootstrap";

const Comp2 = () => {
 return (
  <Col md={11}>
   <content>
  </Col>
 );
}
export default Comp2;
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: So far, I kinda found a workaround, but it's still outside of the criteria I hoped for, I just rendered the second component within the first component's grid system and so I have the original `<Col md={1}> <content> </Col>` but underneath that I have `<Col md={11}> <Comp2 /> </Col>`

This way it looks has the design I wanted, but without using the parent's grid sadly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things:

1. Make sure you have installed both `bootstrap` and `react-bootstrap` using NPM: `npm install bootstrap react-bootstrap`
2. Make sure you import the main css file from bootstrap, so that it can apply the grid styles `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Col, Container, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <Comp1 />
        <Comp2 />
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
}

const Comp1 = () => {
  return <Col md={1}>Hello world</Col>;
};

const Comp2 = () => {
  return <Col md={11}>Foobar</Col>;
};
```

[Codesandox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-matan-s8dl63?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Oh wow, @PsiKai, thanks man xD it's working flawless now!